# Windows 7 activate after renaming

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

Do you need to re-activate Windows 7 after it has been renamed? The machine i'm talking about is a pc that is connected to a domain (at work).

Or is this not necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming your pc does not invalidate your activation status. Only big hardware changes or sometimes  BIOS updates.

Comment: + 1 Totally agree! Although I would say 'Some (most) big hardware changes' as I have gotten away with a few in the past :) .